# VScode V 1.70 not showing Serial monitor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using VSCode v1.70 with platform I/O for ESP32 project on a win 7 machine with a serial monitor and send serial test window. I installed the same version on a win 10 machine but the option to View serial monitor is not in the listing view dropdown. I went through most of the setting options and they appear to be the same but cannot find the view serial monitor. I get terminal view but no send serial window. Are there some other settings that I have not made to get the same setup that I used on the Win7 machine?